# Login to MS Graph with React and MSAL fails with no errors on console

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to use MSAL and React to login to MSGraph. I get the popup to authenticate when I call  `userAgentApplication.loginPopup({propt: "select_account", scopes: config.scopes})`

After entering my login information, it appears that I authenticated but when I try to make a request the login popup continues to display as if I didn't authenticate already. I get no errors on the console.

I refresh the page and check localStorage and see msal.error = invalid_state_error

I'm using MSAL version v1.4.6

Here is my code

ContextualMenu.js

```
import { msgraph } from './actions/graphAction';
const graph = useSelector((state) => state.graph);

const userAgentApplication = new UserAgentApplication({
        auth: {
            clientId: config.appId,
            redirectUri: config.redirectUri
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
            storeAuthStateInCookie: true
        }
    });

const getUserProfile = async () => {
        try {
            let accessToken = await userAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent({
                scopes: config.scopes
            });

            if (accessToken) {
                let user = await getUserDetails(accessToken);
                let uu = {
                    displayName: user.displayName,
                    email: user.mail || user.userPrincipalName,
                    givenName: user.givenName,
                    surname: user.surname
                }
                dispatch(msgraph(true, uu, null));
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };

const msLogin = async () => {
        try {
            await userAgentApplication.loginPopup({
                prompt: "select_account"
            });
            getUserProfile();
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log('failed', err);
        }
    };

const emailFiles = () => {
        setRootClassName('close');
        if (graph.isAuthenticated) {
            checkSelectedFile();
            return false;
        }
        msLogin();
    }
```

After loginPopup is called it never gets to getUserProfile and doesn't error either.

Please any help is appreciated